# clean angularjs output to plain html

Tags: html, angularjs, code-cleanup

I am following a tutorial trying to learn angular but i am getting way messier code than the example is stating is there a flag i need to activate/deactivate i would like to produce clean html open to other suggestions post processing etc.

code:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">Name of the day: {{ ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu',   'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'][day-1] }}</li>
</ul>
```

expected output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Name of the day: Mon</li>
  <li>Name of the day: Tue</li>
  <li>Name of the day: Wed</li>
  <li>Name of the day: Thu</li>
  <li>Name of the day: Fri</li>
  <li>Name of the day: Sat</li>
  <li>Name of the day: Sun</li>
</ul>
```

actual output:

```
<ul>
  <!-- ngRepeat: day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] --><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Mon</li><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Tue</li><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Wed</li><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Thu</li><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Fri</li><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Sat</li><li ng-repeat="day in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Name of the day: Sun</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't need to consider how the output looks. It behaves like the expected output, and that's really the only thing that's important.

Comment: As @Yoshi already stated, your code is doing what you expected. Angular needs such extra markup internally. Do you have any problem with this?

Comment: so its not posable to output without the added markup?

Comment: Nope, and there's no need to do this.

Comment: Why would you need the "expected" output? If you do inspect element on your browser, that's what you should see

Comment: yes i need a clean output not using angular on frontend where the output will be desplayed

Comment: As long as the browser is concerned, you don't **need** clean output. And if you don't explain why you think **you** need it, nobody can help you.

Comment: so i am guessing its just not possible then? my project i was thinking of using angular for is a page builder and i want it to produce clean code. besides that i just think clean clear code is something we should all strive for.

Comment: The *clean* code you're striving for, should be the html/js **before** angular takes over. Not after.

Comment: disagree i think both matter but thanks all for your input

Comment: This is a non issue. This is indeed how angularjs works. It is not possible to generate the code with Angular w/out the added markup. Do you have a specific need that requires an AngularJS page w/out AngularJS markup?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be concerned about how does your HTML code would look on the browser side. Just because it is for the browser. You should be worried about how your HTML partial/template look in the source control - because this is there for developers to read and modify.

Moreover, there is a widely-used [HTML minification task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) which makes HTML code even less readable for a human eye. But, again, this is for the browser - don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for your input i get where you are coming from but don't believe its as black and white as that for example the project i was thinking of using angular would produce html for a front-end dev to style hence clean markup is very important.

Comment: @MitchellBray well, I see your point. Note that, for example, if you open up `chrome developer tools`, `Elements` tab - you will see nicely formatted HTML there. You can use that, don't you?

Comment: yeah thank but its not so much the formatting but the added markup i am currently looking into processing the code with regex before saving but would be nice if angular had a final output option.